# Parsing command line arguments in Perl

Tags: reinventing-the-wheel, perl

I use this idiom to parse command line arguments in Perl:

```
my @args;
my $encode = 1;

while (@ARGV) {
    for (shift(@ARGV)) {
        ($_ eq '-h' || $_ eq '--help') && do { &usage(); };
        # ... more options here
        ($_ eq '--') && do { push(@args, @ARGV); undef @ARGV; last; };
        ($_ =~ m/^-.+/) && do { print "Unknown option: $_\n"; &usage(); };
        push(@args, $_);
    }
}
```

This let's me do things like:

- Supports command line arguments in arbitrary order
- Supports using `--` to use any following arguments "as is", without parsing
- Stop parsing and print usage message on `-h`, or `--help`
- Raise error if a `-something` flag is detected that is not matched by any of the parsing rules

Here's a short example script using this idiom:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

&usage() unless @ARGV;

my @args;
my $encode = 1;

while (@ARGV) {
    for (shift(@ARGV)) {
        ($_ eq '-h' || $_ eq '--help') && do { &usage(); };
        ($_ eq '-D' || $_ eq '--decode') && do { $encode = ! $encode; last; };
        ($_ eq '--') && do { push(@args, @ARGV); undef @ARGV; last; };
        ($_ =~ m/^-.+/) && do { print "Unknown option: $_\n"; &usage(); };
        push(@args, $_);
    }
}

sub usage {
    $0 =~ m|[^/]+$|;
    print "Usage: $& [-h|--help] [-D|--decode]\n";
    print "\n";
    print "Encode (= default) or decode Base64\n";
    exit 1;
}

use MIME::Base64;
if ($encode) {
    print map(&MIME::Base64::encode_base64($_), @args);
} else {
    print map(&MIME::Base64::decode_base64($_), @args);
}
```

Is this a good technique for parsing command line arguments in Perl?
Is there a better way?

I'm also interested in improvement ideas about the short script itself too.

Comment: Why don't you use a standard Perl package such as [Getopt::Std](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) or [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using the `&` sigil to call a subroutine** has gone [out of style since Perl 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347410/1157100) was released in 1994.

**Nesting a for-loop** inside a while-loop is a weird way to express the flow of control, in my opinion.  You want to iterate through `@ARGV` at most once, so it should look like a single loop.  The for-loop isn't really a loop at all; it's just a way for `last` to goto the point after `push(@args, $_)`.  (The use of `for` would be acceptable in conjunction with the [`when` keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements), as it would then be recognizable as a Perl switch statement.)  I think that the following way would be a clearer way to write the loop:

```
while (@ARGV) {
    local $_ = shift @ARGV;
    ($_ eq '-h' || $_ eq '--help') && do { usage(); };
    ($_ eq '-D' || $_ eq '--decode') && do { $encode = ! $encode; next; };
    ($_ eq '--') && do { push(@args, @ARGV); undef @ARGV; next; };
    ($_ =~ /^-./) && do { print STDERR "Unknown option: $_\n"; usage(); };
    push(@args, $_);
}
```

If a solitary `-` is passed on the command line, it is treated as a valid argument to be appended literally to `@args`.  I'm not sure if that is intentional.

---

**Explicitly asking for usage help** differs from displaying help in the case of a usage error.  In the former case, the exit status should be 0, and the display should go to `STDOUT`.  In the latter case, the exit status should be non-zero, and the display should go to `STDERR`.  In addition, I don't recommend burying the `exit()` call inside `usage()`, because it makes your option-parsing loop harder to follow.

```
sub usage {
    my ($status) = @_;
    my $old_fh = select STDERR if $status;

    print …;

    select $old_fh if $old_fh;
    return $status;
}

exit usage(1) unless @ARGV;
while (@ARGV) {
    local $_ = shift @ARGV;
    ($_ eq '-h' || $_ eq '--help') && do { exit usage(0); };
    ($_ eq '-D' || $_ eq '--decode') && do { $encode = ! $encode; next; };
    ($_ eq '--') && do { push(@args, @ARGV); undef @ARGV; next; };
    ($_ =~ /^-./) && do { print STDERR "Unknown option: $_\n"; exit usage(1); };
    push(@args, $_);
}
```

---

**The use of `$encode` is problematic in three ways.**  First, you should use variables that reflect the UI.  Also, prefer to use variables that default to 0 or a false value.  Finally, toggling `$encode` whenever a `--decode` flag is encountered is inappropriate, because it is surprising that `--decode --decode` actually causes it to encode instead of decode.  (Imagine what would happen if one defined a shell alias `rm` as `rm -i`, such that running `rm -i` expands to `rm -i -i`, only to find that file deletion is no longer interactive!)

---

In my opinion, **the code formatting hinders readability**.  Aligning the `do` blocks would help.  However, you might as well be less stingy and place statements on separate lines.

```
my $decode;
while (@ARGV) {
    local $_ = shift @ARGV;
    if ($_ eq '-h' || $_ eq '--help') {
        exit usage(0);
    } elsif ($_ eq '-D' || $_ eq '--decode') {
        $decode = 1;
        next;
    } elsif ($_ eq '--') {
        push(@args, @ARGV);
        undef @ARGV;
        next;
    } elsif (/^-./) {
        print STDERR "Unknown option: $_\n";
        exit usage(1);
    } else {
        push(@args, $_);
    }
}
```

The usage of `next` and `elsif` are redundant.  I think that the redundancy helps make the code easier to follow, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for the great review! I've been using this technique since 2005, too bad (as you say) it was already obsolete then :)

Comment: Excellent review. However, it's perfectly idiomatic to use `for` not as a loop, but as a topicalizer (similar in function to Pascal's `with` statement). Doing `while ($_ = shift @ARGV) { … }` is not necessarily correct: It does not localize `$_`, and has problems with false values. Doing `while (@ARGV) { my $flag = shift @ARGV; … }` would be optimal.

Comment: why are you still localizing `$_`? There is no benifit from it in that case. I would understand, if, at some point, many uses of a function that defaults to `$_` is used. but that way it just obscures the function of the variable. `$argument` or for brevity's sake, `$arg` would help, in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

There are several modules on CPAN that are made for this task. They all reside in the `Getopt` namespace. [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) even comes with the standard distribution. So coming to your question: Yes, there are better ways.

If you are interested in something more fancy, you could have a look at [`Getopt::Declare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Declare) where you can write the usage page and fill your variables in the same place. It has a downside, though since it introduces another DSL.

What I definitely would recommend is that you take a look at `<<HERE` docs for printing longer texts. Some people dislike them,because of their strange syntactic properties, but they are the usual way to express multiline strings in perl.

Comment: For maximum portability, I prefer standard packages that I can safely assume to exist everywhere. I was not aware of `Getopt::Long`, it seems to be a standard package now, I will try to rewrite my script to use it, thanks!

Comment: the build system for perl has greatly improved. and with metacpan's crosslinks to cpantesters you can check for so many system where some modules works.

Comment: @janos According to [Module::CoreList](http://p3rl.org/Module::CoreList) [Getopt::Long](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long) has come with Perl since Perl 5, which was released in 1994.